# Prove that $z=u$ where $z,u$ are complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z,w,u$ are complex number, prove that if $zw=uw\,$ where $w\neq0$ then $z=u$

Let $$zw=uw,\;\;\; w\neq0 $$

I have $$zw-uw = 0$$

i.e. $$w(z-u)=0$$

Thus, $$w=0\quad or\quad (z-u)=0 $$

From $w\neq 0\;$ I have $$(z-u)=0$$

Therefore $$z=u$$

Please check my proof, Thank you!

Comment: There are no errors in your logic, not sure if they are looking for more though considering they specificially defined all variables as complex (this solution holds for real or complex)

Comment: Looks good. This a specific case of a more general phenomenon called the "cancellation property" which holds in integral domains. The complex numbers is an example of an integral domain.

Comment: Looks good. Another thing to consider: If $w \neq 0$ then $1/w$ exists, so...

Comment: Thank you everyone. @siyopao We can multiple by 1/w and we have z=u, right?

Comment: @Zera Yes, exactly!